# Someone explain me..why we are using #1 in the below program

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim strTemp As String
  Open "C:\Ultra Occlusion.txt" For Input As #1

  Line Input #1, strTemp
  Line Input #1, strTemp

  Close #1

  MsgBox strTemp
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Input As #1`. Does this give you a hint?

Comment: Explain me the whole program..how to read a  file using VB6.

Comment: This is not what you asked in the title. Please edit your question. Also understand that this is not a code teaching site.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/line-inputstatement), #1 is a [file number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vbe-glossary) that is specified in the `Open` statement and then used in `Line Input` or `Print` statements to refer to this file.

> > **File number**: Number used in the Open statement to open a file. Use file numbers in the range 1-255, inclusive, for files not accessible to other applications. Use file numbers in the range 256-511 for files accessible from other applications.

Comment: That last sentence is news to me.  I thought the `shared` modifier designated file was to be shareable.  Does this apply to VB6 as well as VBA?

Comment: I did some further research. VB6 has a built-in function `FreeFile` (those golden days when I used this stuff; 20 years since then) that you can use instead of supplying a hard-coded file number. But even `FreeFile` takes an optional parameter (possible values: 0 or 1) that, if specified, returns a file number in the range 0-255 or 256-511. So it looks like VB6 too has a concept of exclusive vs. shared files. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445002(v=vs.60).aspx) and [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?521757-FreeFile(1)-what-does-Open-256-really-do).

Comment: I was going to mention FreeFile and wondered if they modified it to handle this new additional set of returned handles.  I still use VB6 in my accounting software, and in the rare cases where I need to access files in that manner I always use FreeFile - better safe than sorry (File already open error)